# How Devfs and dev file system differ

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, device-driver, kernel

I read about **devfs**(known as device file system ) to facilitate device driver programming as mentioned in linux device drivers text    . How different is **devfs** from **/dev** directory in linux.Are they both same ?, i'm quite confused .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`/dev` is a directory. It tends to have mostly device nodes in it.

devfs is an **obsolete and no longer available** virtual filesystem that automatically generated the contents of `/dev` on some older versions of the Linux kernel. These days, it has been replaced by [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), a daemon that manages the contents of `/dev` in a temporary filesystem, or by [devtmpfs](http://lwn.net/Articles/330985/), which is a lightweight replacement for devfs that is used in some minimal systems.

Comment: Just as a side note, AFAIK, `devfs` is still being used in other unix-based OS, like macOS.

Comment: @YoavAharoni True, after a sense. But the devfs that used to exist in Linux was entirely Linux-specific. The ones that exist in XNU (macOS/iOS) and various BSDs are completely separate implementations; the only things they had in common were their names and their general purpose.

Comment: @duskwuff "used in some minimal systems." `udev` is certainly not restricted to minimal systems! Most distros I know of use it.

Comment: @jpaugh You're parsing that sentence incorrectly. devtmpfs is what's used in some minimal systems, not udev. (Although nowadays that's increasingly rare.)